# Webview Scroll Apply self.view IOS

Tags: objective-c, webview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, scrollview

In my application i have webview and some items above the webview.when i scroll the webview i want to scroll these items also.i tried so many thing it is not possible in scrollViewDidScroll.i need something else.I tried these codes but it is not working efficiently..

```
  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
CGRect webViewFrame = self.contentWebView.frame;

webViewFrame.origin.y -= 3;


CGRect imageViewFrame = self.featuredImageView.frame;
imageViewFrame.origin.y -= 3;


CGRect overlayFrame = self.overlayView.frame;
overlayFrame.origin.y -= 3;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.001 animations:^{
    self.contentWebView.frame = webViewFrame;
    self.featuredImageView.frame = imageViewFrame;
    self.overlayView.frame = overlayFrame;
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CGPoint offset2 = sender.contentOffset;
    offset2.y = 0;
    sender.contentOffset = offset2;

}];
```

}

[image: Webview scroll problem]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add subView (Other items) to your webView.scrollView ;)

Example:  [myWebView.scrollView addSubView: myItem];